# cosmos database to be indexed in pull approach + files

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I have items and files. There is a 1:m relationship between items and files. Items are stored in a relational database and files in folders. The association between items and files is stored in the relational database. Files can be pdfs, word docs, email etc. I intend to POC cognitive search to be able to search items and associated documents.

My current understanding is, that a pull approach might be cheaper in comparison to the push approach when using cognitive search (the latency requirements are not stringent and eventual consistency is OK). Hence, I intend to move the data into a cosmos database, which can then be indexed via the pull approach. Curious, how does this work with the documents? Would I need to crack them on prem?

There is also the option of attachments and blob storage of documents. The latter is most likely more future proofed. I would think that if I put documents into blob storage, cognitive search indexing would still need to crack the documents and apply skills?

Comment: By pull approach, you mean Cognitive Search is pulling the data from the data source (SQL DB or Cosmos DB in your case). Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri - yes that's how Microsoft calls it

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use Cosmos DB? An indexer can pull the data from an Azure SQL database as well to populate Index.

Comment: @GauravMantri - no particular reason although i think cosmos is more flexible as I may require a graph db as well. Do you thin azure sql dbs are cheaper? Can they take schema less JSON?

Comment: `Do you thin azure sql dbs are cheaper?` - Yes. Cosmos can get pretty expensive. `Can they take schema less JSON?` - No. SQL DBs are relational database thus schema bound.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks. I need to try it and see how the costs are. My understanding is that querying can also be expensive - especially if it involves all "rows". Sounds a bit fishy to me. I have to say it is hard to me to give my boss a cost estimate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good approach.  In terms of data sources, Cognitive Search supports CosmosDB and blob storage and some relationship databases.  I would probably:

- Create a new Cognitive Search resource in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com).
- In that Cognitive Search resource, click "Import data" to create a new indexer (this is the "pull" option that you mention above).  You may want to do this twice, assuming that your items are in CosmosDB or a relational DB, and your documents are stored separately in blob storage.
- The first indexer has a data source which points to your items/relationship data in whatever DB you decide to put them, applies any skills that you want, and puts everything in an index.
- The second indexer has a different data source which points to your documents in blob storage, applies any skills that you want, and puts everything in the same index.

If you use indexers, they will take care of the document cracking.  If you push data directly into the index, you will need to crack the documents yourself.

This gives a simple walkthrough of creating an indexer with the portal (skillset is optional, and change the data source to your own data): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-quickstart-blob

Comment: thanks I will digest and possibly accept tomorrow.

Comment: `If you use indexers, they will take care of the document cracking.` - You may want to mention that appropriate skillset must be created and associated with an indexer tied to blob data source for document cracking to work.

Comment: @GauravMantri - would you advice to do the document cracking on prem to safe a lot of money?

Comment: @cs0815 - I am not aware of any tools which will do that. Sorry!

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks - we do this already. I was just wondering, if you think that one could save a lot of money to crack docs on prem and then move to Azure (rather than paying for this "skill").

Comment: One thing you could possibly do is find some open source implementation of the skills you would want. For example, I did a quick search on "extract text from image" and landed up on this post: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-text-from-images-with-python-db9b87fe432b. Will doing something like this work?

Comment: Yes sure. The old build versus buy conundrum. We already use an OCR tool to do this but Azure will be faster and possibly better.